# subsetting dataframe based on multiple conditions from one-hot encoded columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
id  is_happy is_sad is_mad is_sorry
1   1        0      1      0
2   1        0      1      0
3   0        1      1      0
4   0        0      0      1
5   0        1      1      0
6   1        0      1      0
7   1        1      1      1
```

i want to get rows where is_happy, is_sad, and is_sorry equals 1

expected output:

```
id  is_happy is_sad is_mad is_sorry
7   1        1      1      1
```

how can i do this without putting multiple conditions with a slicer like below. this gets difficult with many conditions?

```
df[(df.is_happy == 1) & (df.is_sad == 1) & (df.is_sorry == 1)]
```

Comment: if you have dummies, do `df[df[['is_happy','is_sad','is_sorry']].all(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
out = df[df.drop(['id','is_mad'],1).all(1)]
   id  is_happy  is_sad  is_mad  is_sorry
6   7         1       1       1         1
```

Comment: Using `set_index` to get rid of a column is kinda strange. Better use `.drop("id", axis=1)` to make the intent clear.

Comment: or even better `.drop(columns="id")`

Comment: I think you need to drop `is_mad` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep multiple equality checks compact with `np.logical_and.reduce`. Define a list where each tuple specifies the column and the value to check equality against. Then we combine this with `&` logic to find rows where every condition is True.

This method is easy to extend to situations where you might want some columns to be 0, and others to be 1 (or really any value).

```
import numpy as np

equality_l = [('is_happy', 1), ('is_sad', 1), ('is_sorry', 1)]

m = np.logical_and.reduce([df[col].eq(val) for col,val in equality_l])
df.loc[m]

#   id  is_happy  is_sad  is_mad  is_sorry
#6   7         1       1       1         1
```